# I was never there instead of I have never been there

Tags: past-simple

Is it grammatically correct to say "I was never there" instead of "I have never been there"? I have read in Michael Swan's English grammar book that AmE speakers use the simple past more often. Would my sentence be correct in BrE? If it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct grammar in British English. I think most BrE speakers would use the present perfect in this context, since the meaning is about your present state rather than a particular event in the past.

Note that it is usually possible to add a "time phrase" to correct sentences in the past tense.  It is not possible to add a time phrase to this sentence, which strongly suggests that a present perfect form like "have never been there" is much better.

Comment: Thank you, James K for your reply. Is it wrong to put "never" before "was"? Do you mean "I was never there" is correct but native speakers would most likely use the present perfect?